# SciLab icon not displayed properly

Tags: scilab

I updated Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04. After this, SciLab icon has changed to question mark (?) But it is working. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/;
cp scilab.desktop scilab.desktop.backup;
cat scilab.desktop.backup | sed -e 's|^Icon=.*|Icon=/usr/share/scilab/modules/gui/images/icons/32x32/apps/scilab.png|' > scilab.desktop
```

PS: you have to run this lines as a root.